# Why I can't create a SQLite Database in my Android Application

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-emulator, oncreate

Hi I have a problem with my android application. I want to use a sqlite database for my application and I have one activity with the `onCreate()`,`onPause()` and `onResume()` methods. I have built a class `DatenbankManager` with the that create a Table id and name but if I start my Application with a Emulator I get a message and my Application close after this.

here my DatenbankManager Class:

```
package de.tarasov.database_example_tarasov;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatenbankManager extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DB_Name = "Stundenplanname.db";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String KLASSEN_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE Stundenplan(" +
    "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
            "name TEXT NOT NULL";
    private static final String KLASSEN_DROP = "DROP TABLE IF EXIST Stundenplan";

    //Konstruktor
    public DatenbankManager(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_Name, null, DB_VERSION);

    }

    //Methode wenn eine Datenbank erstellt werden muss
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL(KLASSEN_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

            db.execSQL(KLASSEN_DROP); // Löscht Tabelle wenn nicht vorhanden 
            onCreate(db); //Erstellt Tabelle
    }

}
```

Here my MainActivity:

```
package de.tarasov.database_example_tarasov;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private SQLiteDatabase mDatenbank;
    private DatenbankManager mHelper;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mHelper = new DatenbankManager(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mDatenbank.close(); //Schließt Datenbank

        Toast.makeText(this, 
                getResources().getString(R.string.db_close),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {     
        super.onResume();
        mDatenbank = mHelper.getReadableDatabase(); //Datenbank öffnen

        //Gibt Kurztext aus
        Toast.makeText(this, 
                getResources().getString(R.string.db_open),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
    }

}
```

here is the error message:

[image]

and if I make a debug I see:

```
Source not found.
```

in LogCat I see this:

[image]

I hate this debuger :D

Comment: What's your LogCat output?

Comment: see my Update i maked a screenshot

Comment: Run adb kill-server, adb start-server. That will kick start your debugger and you will get all old messages. :) And dont say that its a excellent logger/monitoring tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot `)` in your create table statement:

```
private static final String KLASSEN_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE Stundenplan(" +
    "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
            "name TEXT NOT NULL);";
```